# Upgrading django-celery and celery - Will tasks get dropped?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am doing the following upgrade on celery in my django project.

django-celery==3.0.11 FROM 2.1.2

CELERY == 3.0.13 FROM celery==2.1.4

My questions is will all my tasks continue to queue up and continue or will some tasks get dropped in the processes? I want to make sure nothing is getting skipped or looked over during the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience in upgrading celery and django-celery although I am using both for an app in production. But as per my understanding, as long as the message broker (rabbitmq in my case) is running, the tasks will be queued up and given to the workers when they are up again.

So it would just be a matter of stopping the celery workers, upgrading both celery and django-celery and starting the workers again.

Although before proceeding, you might want to find out if there are any known issues during upgrading from celery 2.x to 3.x in order to avoid any substantial downtime. May be try this on a dev or staging machine first if possible?

Comment: I forgot to mention we are also changer our Broker to redis. I'm assuming if we shutdown the broker they will get lost then? Is there a way to take a snapshot of currently running tasks and import them perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an indepth knowledge about this but how about changing one thing at a time?